# rmarkdown::render doesn't render plots while the knit button does

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an issue with rendering to a word-document in rmarkdown.

I want to render an rmarkdown file to word, but the same issue also happens with the default rmarkdown-file, so I'll be using this here. This is the code:

````
---
title: "test_default"
output: word_document
date: '2023-04-26'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)```


## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)```


## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)```


Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

When I render it using the knit button, the pressure-plot gets rendered correctly and is shown in word:
[Rendering with the knit-button looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuJPq.png)

When I render it with rmarkdown::render("test2_default.Rmd") from an r-script in the same folder, the pressure-plot can't be displayed by word:
[This translates to "The image can't be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnTfx.png)

The summary of cars and the rest of the text are always displayed correctly. I am using R 4.1. I don't get any errors or warnings when calling rmarkdown::render("test2_default.Rmd").

What could be the issue here? For this project the r-markdowns must be created from an r-script and can't be done manually with the knit-button.

Thank you very much for your help!